# How to use a custom AlertDialog in ListPreference?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am writting a simple app for android, and I want to use a custom `AlertDialog`(no negative button, change font size) in `ListPreference` of `PreferenceScreen`, so I extend `ListPreference` like this:

```
public class ListPreferenceEx extends ListPreference {
    public ListPreferenceEx(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPrepareDialogBuilder(AlertDialog.Builder builder) {        
        super.onPrepareDialogBuilder(builder); // To change body of overridden
        builder.setNegativeButton(null, null);
        builder.setTitle(null);
    }
}
```

Then I click the `ListPreferenceEx` and the `list(AlertDialog)` popped up **without title & negative button**, just like a pop up menu. However, I don't know how to **change font size** of this list. I know `AlertDialog.Builder` can use a layout, but in constructor only:

```
builder = new AlertBuilder(new ContextThemeWrapper(this.getContext(), R.style.xxxTheme));
```

And when I put the above code into onPrepareDialogBuilder and run it, I cannot get the right result:

Case1:  (totally no list show)

```
builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(this.getContext(), R.style.ListDlgTheme));
super.onPrepareDialogBuilder(builder);
```

Case2:  (no effect, the font size is unchanged)

```
super.onPrepareDialogBuilder(builder);
builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(this.getContext(), R.style.ListDlgTheme));
```

How can I set `AlertDialog.Builder's` font size in `onPrepareDialogBuilder` or other override method? Or use a custom `AlertDialog` in `ListPreferenceEx`? Please help me, thanks!

Comment: What prevents you from just having a dedicated layout file for your alert that you want to use in preferences screen?

Comment: see my question edited.

Comment: after your app crashed, what was in the logcat?

Comment: sorry for my poor memory, see the edited detail.